# Не хочет принимать переменную

Tags: php

В общем, нужно сделать, чтоб выводились данные из бд и по клику по ссылке выводилась страница с редактированием информации об этом данном. Хочу сделать это все в один файл, но почему-то не принимает переменную и вообще, ругается. Код получился следующий:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id == '') {
    ...
    while ($count = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        ...
        echo '<a href="/cat.php?id=' . $cat['lname'] . '">' . $cat['name'] . '</a> / <a href="/admin/edite.php?id=' . $count['id'] . ' ">' . $count['title'] . '</a><br> 
<br>
';
    }
}

if ($id == '' . $count['id'] . '') {
    $id = def($_GET['id']);
    ...
?>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="edite.php">
          ...
      </form>
<?
}
?>
```

При переходе на эту страницу почему-то ругается на `$id=def($_GET['id']);` ошибка:

> `Call to undefined function def()`

Так же, при клике на ссылку нет формы редактирования, пустое место. Хотя ссылка `domen.loc/edite.php?id=1`

Comment: @rimlin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = def($_GET['id']);
```

уберите нафиг этот def!

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // прекрасно будет работать, если параметр передан
```

а проверить можно:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
if ($id ==''.$count['id'].'')
```

Надо бы

```
if ($id == $count['id'])
```

Comment: Не помогло... проблема осталась

Comment: что за функция def()? Где она объявлена?

Comment: объявлена внутри if ($id == '' . $count['id'] . ''), что бы принять ид.

Comment: Что за ересь объявлять функцию в условии о_О

Comment: оно не в условие